# ASP .Net core project CI\CD fails in Publish using DevOps Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have an ASP.Net core 2.1 Devops project build and released successfully. But when we try accessing we are getting error.

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
```

If we take the drop from artifacts and try local it is working perfect. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling stdoutLog, we got the following error details.

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '**2.1.0-preview1-final**' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:https://aka.ms/dotnet-download - **The following versions are installed:2.1.2** at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Our application was using '**2.1.0-preview1-final**', seems Azure installed the latest version 2.1.2 for the DevOps environment. We updated our application with **Core 2.1.2** and tried again. **Now the application runs successfully without any error**.

**Thank you** Martin Brandl!

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot will be to **enable logging** to track down the error:

1. Go to the Kudu environment (https://YOURSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net)
2. On the top menu, select Debug console -> PowerShell
3. Navigate to site -> wwwroot and open the web.config
4. Set the stdoutLogEnabled attribute to true and save the file.
5. Create a folder named logs next to the web.config using mkdir logs

Now if you try to browse your site again, you should see a log file within the previously created directory containing additional information.

See also:
[Determine whats wrong with your Azure Web / API App deployment](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/05/determine-whats-wrong-with-azure-web-app-deployment/)

Comment: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0-preview1-final' was not found.  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\ - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:https://aka.ms/dotnet-download - The following versions are installed:2.1.2 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Comment: I answerd the question based on your provided information and helped you track down the errow. No clue why you take back the accept and accept your own answer.